# How to get the day name from a selected date?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this : `Datetime.Now();` or `23/10/2009`
I want this : `Friday`

For local date-time (GMT-5) and using Gregorian calendar.

Comment: after one of the exact same answers here is accepted ...do others clean up? :)

Comment: 6 exact identical answers.. basically XD

Answer (score 145, accepted):

```
//default locale
System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
//localized version
System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd");
```

To make the answer more complete:

- [DayOfWeek MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek%28VS.71%29.aspx)
- If localization is important, you should use the "dddd" string format as [Fredrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93623/fredrik-mork) pointed out - [MSDN "dddd" format article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ddddSpecifier)

Comment: I wouldn't use the ToString. If you need it for comparisons or storage, just use the enum value. Otherwise, using the dddd format specifier as in Fredrik's answer is better for localization.

Comment: The localized version is not correct and gives a compiler error. It should be `System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd");`

Answer (score 17):

If you want to know the day of the week for your code to do something with it, `DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek` will do the job.

If you want to display the day of week to the user, `DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd")` will give you the localized day name, according to the current culture ([MSDN info on the "dddd" format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ddddSpecifier)).

Answer (score 11):

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)
```

or

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DateTime.Parse("23/10/2009").DayOfWeek)
```

Answer (score 8):

`DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek` quite easy to guess actually.

for any given date:

```
   DateTime dt = //....
   DayOfWeek dow = dt.DayOfWeek; //enum
   string str = dow.ToString(); //string
```

Comment: or to keep more simple `Datetime dt; string date = dt.DayOfWeek.ToString()`

Answer (score 8):

Here is more simple

```
DateTime dt;
string yourdate = dt.DayOfWeek.ToString()
```

better than declare redundant DayOfWeek

Answer (score 6):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now
string s = now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the DayOfWeek property.

Here's the [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I use this Extension Method:

```
public static string GetDayName(this DateTime date)
{
    string _ret = string.Empty; //Only for .NET Framework 4++
    var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-419"); //<- 'es-419' = Spanish (Latin America), 'en-US' = English (United States)
    _ret = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(date.DayOfWeek); //<- Get the Name     
    _ret = culture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(_ret.ToLower()); //<- Convert to Capital title
    return _ret;
}
```

Comment: Why this isn't the answer, I'll never know

Answer (score 0):

What about if we use String.Format here

```html
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
String.Format("{0:dd-MM}, {1:dddd}", today, today) //In dd-MM format
String.Format("{0:MM-dd}, {1:dddd}", today, today) //In MM-dd format
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(DateTime.Parse((Eval("date").ToString()))).DayOfWeek.ToString()
```

at the place of **Eval("date")**,you can use any date...get name of day

Answer (score 0):

```
        Random Rnd = new Random();
        RandomDates Rdate = new RandomDates();
        PaymentDetails Payd = new PaymentDetails();
        DayOfWeek strDay = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
        var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        var dateValue2 = dateTime.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy");


        StepDescription = "Fill MatterInformation. ";

        
       

            Console.Write(" Input the Day : ");
            dt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write(" Input the Month : ");
            mn = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write(" Input the Year : ");
            yr = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            DateTime d = new DateTime(2021, 04, yr);
            var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            var diff = d.DayOfWeek - culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
            if (diff < 0)
                diff += 7;
            var x = d.AddDays(-diff).Date;


            dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            dateValue2 = dateTime.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy");
            Console.WriteLine($"Date Value: {dateValue2}");

           // strDay = 

        }
        if (!strDay.Equals("Sunday") | !strDay.Equals("Saturday"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("___________________OK____________________________________________");
            // string NotificateionDate = Rdate.DateWithin_PastDays(Rnd.Next(30, 260)).ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy");

            // CustomLibrary.seWaitUntilElementIsVisible(10, NotiFiedDateTab.Actions.seGetLocator(), "NotiFiedDateTab");
            NotiFiedDateTab.Actions.Set(ControlPropertyNames.Text, dateValue2);

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("_________________________NOT______________________________________");
            if (strDay.Equals("Sunday"))
            {
                dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(-2);
                dateValue2 = dateTime.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy");
                NotiFiedDateTab.Actions.Set(ControlPropertyNames.Text, dateValue2);
            }
            else if (strDay.Equals("Saturday"))
            {

                dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(-1);
                dateValue2 = dateTime.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy");
                NotiFiedDateTab.Actions.Set(ControlPropertyNames.Text, dateValue2);
            }
        }
      
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some insightful commentary on what this code is doing for answer completeness.

Answer (score -2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace GuessTheDay
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
 Console.WriteLine("Enter the Day Number ");
 int day = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 Console.WriteLine(" Enter The Month");
int month = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter Year ");
int year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
DateTime mydate = new DateTime(year,month,day);
string formatteddate = string.Format("{0:dddd}", mydate);
Console.WriteLine("The day should be " + formatteddate);
}  
 } 
   }
```

Comment: Answer is not concise enough. You should read the question properly and give small working example that is easy to read & understand.