# show only weekday from date

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date-format

I'm trying to use a date value I have in my table to show the start date of a holiday as the day value (Monday, Tuesday etc) how would be the best way to go about getting the start day value in this format in VB.NET?

I'm currently working with the date format dd/mm/yy.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I know the day name from a selected date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615380/how-can-i-know-the-day-name-from-a-selected-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Weekday and WeekdayName functions

```
WeekdayName(Weekday(startDate))
```

Weekday , which returns a number that indicates the day of the week of a particular date. It considers the ordinal value of the first day of the week to be one.

WeekdayName , which returns the name of the week in the current culture that corresponds to a particular weekday number.

Comment: Was just waiting for the count down