# Given a string with day of week, return integer

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to have something like:

```
string day = "Sunday";
int num = getDayOfWeek(day); //returns 0
```

I understand we could something like, and I wanted the reverse:

```
int num = 0;

//returns "Sunday"
return System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[(int)num];
```

The easiest way would probably be to implement a dictionary that does what I am asking, but I wonder if there is something in `C#` `DateTime` functions that already does so for me.

EDIT:

As Jon Skeet pointed out, it would be ideal that the answer supported different cultures days (*e.g*. "Sunday" in English, "Segunda" in Portuguese...)

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615380/how-can-i-know-the-day-name-from-a-selected-date) help?

Comment: Do you need to handle multiple cultures?

Comment: @JonSkeet That would be ideal (and is also part of the question), but for now I would be happy to know if there's something like I asked.

Comment: Well I don't believe there's anything built-in... but using ToDictionary with LINQ makes it a one-liner.

Comment: @nthol Not really, that is the reverse of what I am asking.

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought if doing so, and then add it to a DateTimeExtensions class or something like that in order to reuse it. Is there a way to have such dictionary to handle those Culture issues?

Comment: With date.DayOfWeek.ToString() you'll get the day of week as a string.. no need to do getDayOfWeek(day) first.. you`ll have to consider localization as usual with dateTime objects

Comment: @ManuelReis: Not easily. You'd have to consider storing the dictionary somewhere in order to reuse it.

Comment: @MarcWittmann Keep in mind that I am not using a DateTime object, just that weekday string.

Comment: You can store day names with : `var dayNameDictionary = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames.Select((s, i) => new { key = i, value = s }).ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var inx = Array.FindIndex(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames, x=>x=="Sunday");
```

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following:

```
string myDay = "Tuesday";
int dayNumber = ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), myDay)); // dayNumber = 2
```

Each day of the week is mapped to the following number:

```
- Sunday = 0
- Monday = 1
- Tuesday = 2
- Wednesday = 3
- Thursday = 4
- Friday = 5
- Saturday = 6
```

Comment: Would this support different cultures?

Comment: @ManuelReis No, it would not. But if you don't mind that limitation, this is the simplest answer so far.