# how to get specific day in date range

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

i want to get specific day that i want in date range any idea how to do this,

how to get "Saturday" from List range : in below code

```
 var startDate =  dtpInsetDate.Value.ToDate();
                var endDate = dtpEndDate.Value.ToDate();
                int days = (endDate - startDate).Days + 1; // incl. endDate 
                string day = endDate.Day.ToString();
                List<DateTime> range = Enumerable.Range(0, days)
                 .Select(i => startDate.AddDays(i))
                 .ToList();
                if (day.StartsWith("Sat") == true)
                { 

                }
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Your code isn't working? It throws exception or error? Unexpected result? What `ToStr` and `ToDate` do exactly? Please be more specific.

Comment: i want get day in range variable , like Only Saturday

Comment: how to get "Saturday" from List<DateTime> range

Comment: @AdeelKhan what about multiple possible saturdays in this range? do you need all of them or some specific?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I know the day name from a selected date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615380/how-can-i-know-the-day-name-from-a-selected-date)

Comment: Concider using `DayOfWeek` property of `DateTime`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you want the first Saturday in your range.

```
var saturday = range.FirstOrDefault(dt => dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday);
```

Or this if you want all saturdays in your range:

```
var saturday = range.Where(dt => dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday);
```

Comment: The variable `saturday` is a `DateTime`.  If you want to see the name of the day just use: `saturday.DayOfWeek.ToString()`.

Comment: can i compare this ?  var seletedday = range.Where(dt => dt.DayOfWeek == ddlweekdays.Text.ToDate());

Comment: No. ToDate() returns a DateTime. DayOfWeek represents an Enum.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DayOfWeek property on the DateTime Object.

```
        var dayList = new List<DateTime>();

        foreach(var day in dayList)
        {
            if (day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) //Sunday
            if (day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday) //Monday
            etc...
        }
```

Or Linq

```
        dayList.Where(x => x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to get "Saturday" from List range

Based on your comment;

```
DateTime saturday = range.Where(d => d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday).FirstOrDefault();
```

I assumed your range has only *one* Saturday, this will return it.