# How do I extract the day from this DateTime variable?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I want to extract the name of the day as string from this:

```
Holder.CurrentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(countNext).ToLongDateString();
Holder.CurrentDay = ?
```

Where `Holder.CurrentDay` is a `string`. I have tried:

```
Holder.CurrentDay = Holder.CurrentDate.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

But `DayOfWeek` does not exist as a function in this context. Do you guys have any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: How can we help you? We have no idea how `Holder` is implemented. Also, if you want to get `DayOfWeek` you must not convert the DateTime object to a string first.

Comment: `Holder.CurrentDate` type is `DateTime` or `string`? (I guess it is `string`). `string` type indeed does not have a `DayOfWeek` property

Comment: This one seems similar to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615380/how-can-i-know-the-day-name-from-a-selected-date

Comment: Just stop using strings to store dates. Ask yourself why you are storing a date in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
var CurrentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays( 4 ).ToLongDateString();
var CurrentDay = Convert.ToDateTime(CurrentDate).DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

But its better to store the DateTime itself in a variable instead of converting it back:

```
var theDateWeNeed = DateTime.Now.AddDays( 4 );
//Now we can do this:
Holder.CurrentDate = theDateWeNeed.ToLongDateString();
Holder.CurrentDay = theDateWeNeed.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better to use `ToString` with a format pattern if what you ultimately want is a string. Then you have control over language, etc.

Use the "dddd" pattern to get the name of the day of the week.

```
var dayOfWeek = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd");
```

Pass a second CultureInfo parameter if you want it in a specific language.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, sorry...

```
Holder.CurrentDay = DateTime.Now.AddDays(countNext).DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

Comment: You could better save your date time object with days added

Comment: You should never store the representation of data. Store the data itself (here `DateTime` value) and use that to read the representation from that

Comment: I know, im just doing things quick for now :p

Answer (score 0):

You cannot invoke `DayOfWeek` on `string`. i.e. you have to convert it back or use the same `DateTime` as you did in your previous statement.

```
Holder.CurrentDay = DateTime.Now.AddDays(countNext).DayOfWeek.ToString();
```